# GeneratorExit, close() does not cause a traceback/exception - how?

Tags: python

```
def receiver():
    print("Ready to receive")
#   try:
    while True:
        n = (yield)
        print("Got %s" % n)
#    except GeneratorExit:
#        print("Receiver done")

r  = receiver()
r.next()

r.send(10)

r.close()
```

When I comment out the `GeneratorExit`, the `close()` does not generate traceback! Why? However with the `except` active, i'm able to catch the `GeneratorExit`. How is that possible?

If `GeneratorExit` is an exception, then it should behave like all other exceptions and propagate out which it is doing - hence my ability to catch it using an `except`. But then surely without the `except` the parent python interpreter should catch the traceback like what happens with all other exceptions. What magic's going on here?

Comment: Because the `while` implicitly catches it?

Comment: but if 'while' is catching it implicitly then how does it propagate to the try/except that encloses it? How do they communicate (IPC)? pydoc while doesn't mention anything about GeneratorExit anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [generator.close() documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator.close).

It is stated that `StopIteration` and `GeneratorExit` exceptions are used internally to dictate how the generator exits, and thus are the only exceptions that are not propagated to the caller.

So if you want to re-raise a `GeneratorExit` exception, you probably have to catch it and encapsulate it in another custom exception.